# Theano, My code is always different results come out With gpu(Titan X)

Tags: theano

I am making a simple model with titan X. But  every time the result is different.

It is a simple model.
1. Averaging embedding of words
2. Using a hidden layer input
3. Binary Classifier using softmax

In the each learning process, cost value  Subtly different.
predict result also Subtly different.( ex) First attempt: 56.43, Second attempt: 56.34 .... )
Strange thing is, if do not update  Embedding Layer, It is equal to all the experimental result.

However, When testing with GTX 970,  It same with learning process-cost value  subtly different.
But predict result, It is equal to all the experimental result.

I know CuDNN that can cause this. But I'm not use CNN architecture. just average, relu, softmax...

Help me if you know this problem.

The environment is as follows.
1. GPU: TITAN X
2. theano version:  0.9.0
3. OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Thanks....

Comment: does it happen because of "random" factor when you initialize weights?